# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed;

Tags: spring-mvc

This is my HTML form.

```
<form th:object="${consent}" action="../users/userDetails.html" th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.servletPath}}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
            <label for="last_name">Service  Provider</label>
            <select id="provider" name="provider" class="form-control" th:onchange="'javascript:showPIIDoc(this.value);'">
                <option th:value="0" >Select a Service Provider</option>
                    <option id="provider_id"  th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  th:field="*{provider_id}" th:value="${user.id} +','+ ${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>
                </select>

            </div>  
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
            <label for="last_name">PII Document</label>
            <select id ="documentdiv"  class="form-control">

                </select>
            </div>  
            <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
            <label for="last_name">Share with</label>
            <select  class="form-control">
                <option th:value="0" >Select a user you want share the document to</option>
                    <option id="friend_id" name="name" th:each="user : ${users}"  th:field="*{friend_id}"  th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.firstName} + ' ' + ${user.lastName}">[name]</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <label for="last_name">Consent</label>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="status" th:field="*{status}" name="share" th:value="1" th:text="Share" />
             </div> 

             <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px" class="form-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Consent</button>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the GET Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/providers/{providerId}/documents/{documentId}/consents/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initNewConsentForm(@PathVariable("userId") int userId,@PathVariable("providerId") int providerId,@PathVariable("documentId") int documentId, Model model) {
    User user = this.clinicService.findUserById(userId);
    Provider provider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
    Document document = this.clinicService.findDocumentById(documentId);
    Collection<User> users = this.clinicService.AllUsers();

    Consent consent = new Consent();
        model.addAttribute("provider",provider);
        model.addAttribute("document", document);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("consent", consent);
        return "providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm";

}
```

This is the POST controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}/providers/{providerId}/documents/{documentId}/consents/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processNewConsentForm(@PathVariable("userId") int userId, @PathVariable("providerId") int providerId, 
        @PathVariable("documentId") int documentId, @ModelAttribute("consent") Consent consent, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {

    System.out.print("consentcontroller11");

    User user = this.clinicService.findUserById(userId);
    Provider provider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
    System.out.println("daghade");
    System.out.println(provider);
    Document doc = this.clinicService.findDocumentById(userId);

    Consent c =new Consent();
        c.setProvider(provider);
        c.setDocument(doc);
        c.setUser(user);
        c.setStatus(c.getStatus());
        c.setFriend(c.getFriend());

        System.out.println(c);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm";
    } else {
        this.clinicService.saveConsent(c);
        status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/users/{userId}";
}

}
```

the model

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "consents")
public class Consent extends BaseEntity {

```
/**

 */
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
private Provider provider;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "friend_id")
private User friend;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "document_id")
private Document document;

private String status;

/**
 * C
 * @return 
 */
public void Provider() {
}

public Provider getProvider() {
    return this.provider;
}

/**
 * Setter for property pet.
 *
 * @param pet New value of property pet.
 */
public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}


public User getUser() {
    return user;
}


public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}


public User getFriend() {
    return friend;
}


public void setFriend(User friend) {
    this.friend = friend;
}


public Document getDocument() {
    return document;
}


public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
}


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}


public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

I am getting this error

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring3.processor.attr.SpringOptionFieldAttrProcessor' (providers/createOrUpdateConsentForm:248)

Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: post more detailed stack trace . thanks

Comment: Looks an awful lot like the first result you get when Googling the error : http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Not-able-to-resolve-Java-exception-in-validation-td4027992.html

Comment: I added the consent model class

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: no i am stuck still! The problem is with the GET declaration

Comment: what more information should i provide? the repository information?

Comment: the problem i see is this line:   <option class="form-control" aria-required="true" id="provider_id" th:errors="*{provider_id}" th:each="provider : ${user.providers}"  th:field="*{provider_id}" th:value="${user.id} +','+ ${provider.id}" th:text="${provider.name}" >[name]</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
  <option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" 
          th:value="${type}" 
          th:text="#{${'seedstarter.type.' + type}}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

th:field should be in select and that should capture as variable for iteration.

Comment: the problem moved to the line containing th:field in the select statement

Comment: on POST decleration I get this error: Field or property 'providers' cannot be found on null